Integration of a very hard expression
I came across this integration problem in my module but I am unable to crack it. Here it is--
Find in terms of 'a'. $$\int_0^\infty {x^a}e^{-x} dx$$
I have tried substitution and integration by parts but I am unable to solve it.
Can anyone help me?

Do you now the gamma function?

Please avoid expressions like "very hard", "urgent", and similar ones in the title. Use mathematical terms.

For all $n \in \mathbb {N}$, see
$$\begin{align} \int_{0}^{\infty} {t}^{n} {e}^{- t} \text {d} t & = - \int_{0}^{\infty} {t}^{n} \cdot \frac {\text {d}}{\text {d} t} {e}^{- t} \cdot \text {d} t \\ & = - {\Big[ {t}^{n} {e}^{- t} \Big]}_{t = 0}^{t \to \infty} + \int_{0}^{\infty} {e}^{- t} \cdot \frac {\text {d}}{\text {d} t} {t}^{n} \cdot \text {d} t = n \int_{0}^{\infty} {t}^{n - 1} {e}^{- t} \text {d} t. \end{align}$$
This can be obtained by integration by parts. By induction, then,
$$\int_{0}^{\infty} {t}^{n} {e}^{- t} \text {d} t = n!,$$
where $n!$ is the $n$th factorial.
EDIT:
If $n \not \in \mathbb {N}$, there is no closed form in terms of elementary functions, in general. But considering its significance, we define a new function: For all $\mathfrak {Re} \left( z \right) > 0$,
$$\Gamma \left( z \right) = \int_{0}^{\infty} {t}^{z - 1} {e}^{- t} \text {d} t.$$
This is the famous gamma function. Integrating by parts, $\Gamma \left( z + 1 \right) = z \; \Gamma \left( z \right)$. Specially, we have $\Gamma \left( 1 / 2 \right) = \sqrt {\pi}$; this can be derived by relating it to the Gaussian integral.

What if n does not belongs to Natural numbers$?$ I guess you should add the gamma function too

@MathStackexchangeIsMarvellous, I've edited my post. Thanks for commenting.
